# Is there any GNOME extension to display account name in the top bar instead of a group of function button?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, username

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

I am new to GNOME Desktop and I want to customize it a little bit. As seen on 16.04 (Unity Desktop), those function button (as picture below) display as my account name. I want to know if there is a extension help me to change that?

[image: here is the picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gnome-shell-extension named "Add Username to Top Panel"
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1108/add-username-to-top-panel/

[image]