# How do I display username on the GNOME menu bar on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.10, gnome-shell-extension, username

In Ubuntu 19.10 and the GNOME Shell version 3.34.3, I want my username to be shown on the top right corner. I tried the following GNOME Shell extensions but nothing changed.

- [Simple Name](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/807/simple-name/)
- [Add Username to Top Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1108/add-username-to-top-panel/)

Please let me know if you've any solution.

Comment: @DevashSoni Did you try this? https://askubuntu.com/a/1198699/739431

Comment: @K7AAY , I tried these extensions .But none of them worked. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/807/simple-name/ and https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1108/add-username-to-top-panel/

Comment: @PRATAP Yes. But it didn't work.

Comment: how did you install that extension? do u have gnome tweaks installed??

Comment: Please always [edit] your question and add important info, comments section is not the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Workaround***

This Extension should work even in Ubuntu 19.10 which uses Gnome Shell Version 3.34.X https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1108/add-username-to-top-panel/

I have tested it. However I have made a script, taken source from above link..

1. open gedit.
2. copy paste below content and save the file in your home directory with name `username.sh`

*Content:*

```
#!/bin/bash

file1=$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/add-username-toppanel@brendaw.com/extension.js
file2=$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/add-username-toppanel@brendaw.com/metadata.json
file3=$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/add-username-toppanel@brendaw.com/stylesheet.css

install -Dv /dev/null $file1
install -Dv /dev/null $file2
install -Dv /dev/null $file3

echo 'const Clutter = imports.gi.Clutter;
const St = imports.gi.St;
const Main = imports.ui.main;
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib;

let label;
let aggregateMenu;
let children;

function init() {
  label = new St.Label({ text: GLib.get_real_name(), y_align: Clutter.ActorAlign.CENTER, style_class: "username-label" });
  aggregateMenu = Main.panel.statusArea["aggregateMenu"];
  powerIndicator = aggregateMenu._power.indicators;
}

function enable() {
  powerIndicator.add_child(label);
}

function disable() {
  powerIndicator.remove_child(label);
}
' >> $file1

echo '{
"name": "Add Username to Top Panel",
"description": "Simply add your username to topbar panel aggregate menu",
"uuid": "add-username-toppanel@brendaw.com",
"shell-version": ["3.34"]
}' >> $file2

echo ".username-label {
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}" >> $file3

gnome-extensions enable add-username-toppanel@brendaw.com
```

3. Open terminal and run the below

*Command:*

```
/bin/bash $HOME/username.sh
```

4. Refresh the gnome-shell with "Alt+F2 'r' Enter" Method.

[image]

---

When you want to delete the extension, run the below
Command:

```
rm -r $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/add-username-toppanel@brendaw.com
```

and refresh the gnome-shell with "Alt+F2 'r' Enter" Method

Comment: Thanks. It works.

Comment: Yes. I've tried editing it and customized it in multiple ways. Also, I found that it could be installed using 'Ubuntu Software' application. Thanks again.